# Reading specific byte lengths of a byte array vector in rust

Tags: arrays, rust

I have a buffer of `Vec<u8>` type which is the encoding representation as follows where `u16` is the length 16 byte length indication of the message size and `d1..6` is the data:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----------------------------
| b1 | b2 | d1 | d2 | d3 | d4 | d5 | d6 | b1 | b2 | d11 | d12 | ...
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----------------------------
```

I am currently deserializing this by doing the following (eg. 8 bytes):

```
use std::io::Cursor;
use byteorder::{ReadBytesExt, BigEndian};

pub struct Message {
    pub data: Vec<u8>
}

fn deserialize_buffer(buffer: Vec<u8>) -> Message {
    let buffer_copy = buffer.to_vec();
    let mut r = Cursor::new(buffer);

    let data_length: u16 = r.read_u16::<BigEndian>().unwrap();
    if data_length + 2 > buffer_copy.len() as u16 {
        panic!("Invalid Encoding Length");
    }

    let mut data: Vec<u8> = vec![];
    for i in 0..data_length {
        data.insert(i as usize, r.read_u8().unwrap());
    }

    Message{data}
}
```

Is there a better way to do read and store **exact number of bytes** with the `Cursor` instead of using a `for` loop in rust?

Comment: If you are going to read `u8` for the rest you can consume  `Vec<u8>` from `Cursor` : https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e74732b4092cb02b7f51b14ec217809c , Also it is better if you clone buffer's length instead of itself, since you'll just need length, otherwise that would be a waste

Comment: Thank you @ÖmerErden That is indeed helpful, but I was looking for a `n` byte reader for cases where my input buffer has multiple blocks of such data `bbdddddbbddddddddbbdddddddddbbdddddd` where `bb` is the `u16` size of the buffer to read and `d...d` until the next `bb` is the values I want to store as `Vec<Vec<u8>>`.

Comment: I've also clarified the question. Thank you again @ÖmerErden